# Three.js BufferGeometry.toJSON - Why are the Attribute data not exported?

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I am trying to export a buffer geometry to a JSON file.

Here is the code I am using:

```
var output = object.geometry.toJSON();

try 
{
    output = JSON.stringify( output, null, '\t' );
    output = output.replace( /[\n\t]+([\d\.e\-\[\]]+)/g, '$1' );
} 
catch ( e ) 
{
    output = JSON.stringify( output );
}

alert ("Done JSON ");
```

This produces a JSON text object such as this:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "version": 4.4,
        "type": "BufferGeometry",
        "generator": "BufferGeometry.toJSON"
    },
    "uuid": "F871289F-C8FF-4760-A6EA-C9E5FD956702",
    "type": "PlaneBufferGeometry",
    "width": 7500,
    "height": 7500,
    "widthSegments": 15,
    "heightSegments": 15
}
```

However the geometry contains various arrays of attribute data (positions, normals, colors, UVs) which are not included in the JSON text.

I have located the relevant code in the current build of THREE.js (R79) (line 12295 onwards):

```
toJSON: function () {

var data = {
    metadata: {
        version: 4.4,
        type: 'BufferGeometry',
        generator: 'BufferGeometry.toJSON'
    }
};

// standard BufferGeometry serialization

data.uuid = this.uuid;
data.type = this.type;
if ( this.name !== '' ) data.name = this.name;

if ( this.parameters !== undefined ) {

    var parameters = this.parameters;

    for ( var key in parameters ) {

        if ( parameters[ key ] !== undefined ) data[ key ] = parameters[ key ];

    }

    return data; // *** No attributes have been considered yet!

}

data.data = { attributes: {} };   // *** attributes are not defined yet!
```

It appears from the code logic (and confirmed by debugging) that the "data" object is returned from the .toJSON function before the attributes are even considered.

So is it a bug or am I missing something here?

**UPDATE**

U1: As suggested by /u/Radio/ I tried converting the BufferGeometry to a normal THREE.geometry and then running .toJSON() on that.  It worked, all the vertex data was included in the JSON file.

U2: In my particular PlaneBufferGeometry I have modified vertex positions after creation.  The THREE code (above) looks for a .parameters property of the geometry and if it finds one it returns the data and exits the .toJSON function without carrying on to include the various attributes in the output JSON file.  This seems a strange thing to do.

U3: I tried deleting the .parameters property from the BufferGeometry.  After which the BufferGeometry.toJSON() function does produce an output which includes the expected/desired various attribute array data.  This does not seem to compromize further working of the Sculpter (but I am not sure it is a safe hack).

Comment: BufferGeometry is not tracked by javascript. For true export of geometry you need to convert bufferGeometry to geometry.  new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(yourBufferGeometry)....toJSON()

Comment: @Radio. Thanks. I see that might be a possible route to follow. (But if you are right then it is rather strange that the THREE.js code in my question describes specifically a conversion from BufferGeometry to JSON.)

Comment: Not really. The function toJSON can be used for other things. For example I use it for state of an application for saving a scene. The uuids map to OBJ files sitting on a cloud server. The function toJSON is specifically a literal object state stringification, not a 3d file format conversion. For examples of export of 3d from three.js see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/js/exporters

Comment: @Radio. Maybe you are referring to a toJSON function in javascript?  Whereas I am referring to the BufferGeometry.toJSON function in THREE.js (whose opening code is listed in my question).

Comment: Nope. I am not sure where you got the idea that toJSON has any expectation of containing geometry. It converts the literal JavaScript object to convenient JSON that won't have application level junk in it like drawRange and listeners, which you'd get if you used JSON.stringify directly. The JavaScript object type you're using, bufferGeometry, does not hold geometry, and so you don't get any.

Comment: @Radio  Please note that I am using THREE.BufferGeometry.toJSON() not the javascript object/function you keep referring to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117976/discussion-between-steveow-and-radio).